# I'm trying to parse some table and they have some weird alphabet-like non-ascii character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, text, encoding

ＲＩＺＡＬＴＥ

I have some weird characters like the ones above.
On google, it works and it even searches the same characters on the web browser search function, but it does not match on the ruby console.

What is this..?
Is there some kind of table that can replace this to normal alphabets?

Comment: You're not making sense without providing actual context that we can look at for ourselves

Comment: Here is a link to a page that may help you better formulate your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Those are Unicode full-width Latin characters. The first, for example, is [U+FF32](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff32/index.htm), FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R. You can convert these to "normal" Latin characters via [Unicode normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization).

If you're using Ruby 2.2 or newer you can use the built-in [`String#unicode_normalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize) method:

```
"ＲＩＺＡＬＴＥ".unicode_normalize(:nfkc)
# => "RIZALTE"
```

`:nfkc` refers to the type of normalization, NFKC, which is beyond the scope of this answer, but it's worth reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) if you want to know what's actually going on here.

For earlier versions of Ruby, if you're using Rails you can use the [`ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars#normalize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html#method-i-normalize) method, which you can access via `String#mb_chars`:

```
"ＲＩＺＡＬＴＥ".mb_chars.normalize
# => "RIZALTE"
```

ActiveSupport uses NFKC by default.

Comment: Current versions of Ruby also include [unicode normalization](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize), so it’s easy even if you’re not using Rails. The defaults are different from Rails though, so you need to specify the normalization form as a parameter: `"ＲＩＺＡＬＴＥ".unicode_normalize(:nfkc)`.

Comment: Ah neat, didn't know this was possible without AS.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @matt! I've updated my answer.